# Change anchor text with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to change the text of an anchor tag. I've done this before by targeting the DIV it is in and then targeting the anchor tag within that DIV. But without any div or assigned ID on the anchor tag I'm lost. Here is what I have so far:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" class="small quality hide-forsmall" >Link Text</a>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var anchor=document.getElementsByClassName("quality");
anchor.innerHTML="Changed Text";
```

Comment: Try `var anchor=document.getElementsByClassName("quality")[0]`

Comment: When should the code run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get each of the elements with that specific class name, you need to loop through the collection.  Here is a quick example:

http://jsfiddle.net/QU7Kv/1/

```
<a href="#" class="small quality hide-forsmall" >Link Text</a>


<script>
    (function (){
        var anchor=document.getElementsByClassName("quality");
        for(var i = 0; i < anchor.length; i++){
            anchor[i].innerHTML="Changed Text";
        };
     })()
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

[**document.getElementsByClassName**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) returns a [**HtmlCollection**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) of elements matching the class name.

To get the first one use:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("quality")[0];
```

To change the text in all matching elements, iterate over them, similar to:

```
for(var i = 0; i < anchor.length; i++){
    anchor[i].innerHTML="Changed Text";
}
```

Alternatively you can also use [**querySelector()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) which will return the first match only and therefor returns a single element only, similar to:

```
var anchor=document.querySelector(".quality");
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("quality");
```

Method `getElementsByClassName` returns `HTMLCollection`, not a single node. If you want to access the first result, try this:

```js
var anchor = document.getElementsByClassName("quality")[0];
anchor.innerHTML = "Changed Text";
```

More info about `getElementsByClassName`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByClassName returns `HTMLCollection`. Please refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName.